# Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity Plugin for Unity 2019.4.25f & later Doesn't Install The Samples Folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr, google-vr-sdk

I need to upgrade the Google Cardboard plugin in my VR apps. The Unity documentation says that we should use the Google Cardboard for Unity plugin because Unity no longer includes Google Cardboard. I'm using Unity 2019.4.37f.

I followed the steps to import the plugin using Git on link [Quickstart for Google Cardboard for Unity](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart). I saw the progress indicators while the plugin was installed. I went into **XR Plug-in Management** in **Project Settings** and checked **Google XR Plugin**.

I want to create the sample app so I can see what I need to update in my existing VR apps. The instructions say after the plugin is installed I should go to **Assets/Samples/Google Cardboard//Hello Cardboard**. When I go into the Package Manager window the plugin is not listed so I can't import the sample app.

Has anyone had this problem?

UPDATE: I submitted my issue to the GitHub GoogleVR/Cardboard repository. This link has more details including a Unity screenshot of what happened.

https://github.com/googlevr/cardboard/issues/360

Answer (score 0):

This is the response I received from GitHub. You can see the details in the GitHub link.

"In the top left corner of the package manager, it says "Unity Registry". Click on that button and change it to "In Project". You should now see something similar to what is in the following image:"

I did this and was able to access the **Google Cardboard for Unity** plugin in the **Package Manager** window with a link to download the **Hello Cardboard project**. I suggested that they update the instructions for new people that have never used the plugin.